# what is the best/preferred approach to implement multi-threading in android app

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm a beginner in android development and I'm trying to implement an android udp client, which connects to a java server and sends/receives some packets from it.In this process it collects some data (like round-trip delay etc), which is used to measure the QoS of that particular network. I have tried implementing the connection and sending/receiving data using Java Threads, but the application crashes, and hangs if i try to use more than 2 threads. So I'm looking for alternatives. While going through this site as well as some other links I found that in android multiple threads can be implemented using AsyncTask, Handler etc. Also I found that the Service class also helps to run a background service in an app. Please suggest which approach among these would be the best to achieve my purpose.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: After going through some online articles, I came across Executor and ExecutorService. So this is what I tried out:
Within the main activity class, I created two runnable objects to handle sending and receiving of datagrams. Then I started these two threads by calling the execute method on the executor, and passing the runnable objects as parameters. Although now the java server running on my pc receives the packets continuously, the android client is unresponsive.In other words, the UI does not respond. I do not know where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is not one right answer that can be applied as a broad stroke to how to do Android multi-threading.  There are a few different ways to approach it based on what your specific needs are.

Any long running, blocking call, in Android will result in the application crashing.

The most common solution is to use an AsyncTask though. For example, when I want to make a call out to a web API endpoint for some XML data within an Activity I would in this case use an AsyncTask and kick off the calls from within doInBackground.

This is not an appropriate solution though if the wait time is longer, or possibly an unknown wait time.  Or in a situation where there will always be waiting such as a message queuing service.  In this type of situation it may be best to write a separate app based on extending the Service class.  Then you can send/receive notifications to/from the service from your primary application in a similar manner to how you would communicate with a web service.

Comment: well yes, the execution time for the thread is quite long, since the app needs to transmit packets continuously until the user stops transmission. The approach which I used earlier was to create separate threads each for sending and receiving datagrams. But, the problems I faced by using threads was crashing of the program, and unresponsive UI. So, if I were to use Service, should I create a separate service for each separate thread of execution? Also, links to some appropriate articles would be helpful.

Comment: Here is a link to a good tutorial. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html.  Make sure you are setting up your service to run in it's own process or it will block the main thread and can cause crashing.  An AsyncTask will automatically spin itself in to a separate thread and then release itself when it is done, but it sounds like you probably need to go the service route.

Comment: thanks for the link. I will definitely go through it and try to implement my app accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can use AasyncTask to do this and as you mentioned service may be useful too, where u can let your application do whatever it wants in background , if user needs to use application by its interface then AsyncTask must be used to avoid Crashing

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how AsyncTask can be used to avoid crashing?

Comment: The reason of using AsyncTask is to handle a network requests or whenever u r trying to do read write database , cause android system will remove the application which is not response for 5-10 seconds (ANR) that will cause crashing the app , so you need to put your network requests into AsyncTask to do it in background , in this way user will wait for finishing the network requests